# Microsoft SQL Server MERGE deadlock issue

Tags: sql-server, deadlock, merge

I am using Microsoft SQL Server version:

> Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (RTM) - 13.0.1601.5 (X64)   Apr 29 2016 23:23:58   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2016 Datacenter 6.3  (Build 14393: ) (Hypervisor)

I have a stored procedure using a `MERGE` statement that is named `[UpdateReports]`
[image]

`ReportType` is a user-defined type like below:

[image]

When I run the `UpdateReports` procedure, it works good in normal situations.  But when it is executed while a full backup is running on the database, Update Statistic (I think many reads of DB), this `UpdateReports` procedure deadlocks and it takes about 10 minutes to complete.

Is it because I am using `HOLDLOCK` ?

I searched this issue and many people saying MERGE is not stable....

Could you please let me know if there is any good alternative instead of `MERGE`?

If I can use `IF/ELSE, UPDATE/INSERT` instead of `MERGE`.... I am worried about concurrency

Comment: >>>this UpdateReports procedure deadlock and it takes about 10 minutes to complete<<< Any deadlock is resolved by server in less than 5 seconds, so what you are talking about? Locking?

Comment: Can you post details on the deadlock, including the deadlock graph? Are you seeing a single deadlock or many deadlocks? Also, including the `formatted code` is preferred over a screenshot, as it makes it easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are talking about is not "`deadlock` issue", it's not even `blocking` issue.

`Full backup` locks nothing, but when it happens you have intesive `I/O operations`, it's just increasing server load. `Full backup` should be done with the less possible activity on the server, but your activity is not even readonly, it's data modification. If your db is in `simple recovery model`, making merge during `full backup` means `fully logging`, so you have more writelog on inserts.

`Update statistics` really can deadlock with `merge` when it reads `indexes` in opposite order, I saw the cases. But it's surely not your case:

> The system task Deadlock Monitor wakes up **every five seconds** and
>   checks if there  are any deadlocks in the system. When a deadlock is
>   detected, SQL Server rolls back one  of the transactions with the
>   error 1205. That releases all locks held in that transaction  and
>   allows the other sessions to continue.

[Expert SQL Server Transactions and Locking: Concurrency Internals for SQL Server Practitioners
By Dmitri Korotkevitch](https://books.google.it/books?id=J6lxDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA110&lpg=PA110&dq=%22The%20system%20task%20Deadlock%20Monitor%20wakes%20up%20every%20five%20seconds%20and%20checks%22&source=bl&ots=EbLxOHbdNk&sig=ACfU3U0vNbiPDzKiJy3wAquCNO10cSCGbg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiW4PbUqtzkAhVvTBUIHauGBMoQ6AEwAnoECAQQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22The%20system%20task%20Deadlock%20Monitor%20wakes%20up%20every%20five%20seconds%20and%20checks%22&f=false)

So when you say that your task completes in 10 minutes it's definitely not a case of a `deadlock`: even if it could be `UPDATE STATISTICS` to be rollbacked, it happened in some seconds, then it was killed and your `merge` continued as usual.

To find out the exact cause of slowness you should monitor `sys.dm_os_waiting_tasks` during the execution to detect for what your `merge` is waiting for.

Comment: @George.Palacios I updated my answer